# Load DataGrid rows with foreign keys using ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am attempting to load a series of rows into a DataGrid which contain foreign keys to other tables. In this specific case the rows have a TransactionTypeID (foreign key to the TransactionTypes table) that I'd like my ComboBox (ItemsSource is of type DataView from the Transactions Table) to display properly and allow modification.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Transaction Types">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Need ComboBox SelectedText here!"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.TransactionTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                SelectedValuePath="ID"
                SelectedItem="{Binding TransactionTypeID}"></ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The ComboBox SelectedItem doesn't seem to be working and I'm clueless on how to populate the TextBlock text.

Comment: Can you describe what it is about the ComboBox SelectedItem that doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: @EdPlunkett The ComboBox does not have a selection.

Comment: You select an item from the list and the combobox remains blank?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No, the default selection from the row does not get populated.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to set the value of the column and display the transaction type description based on the particular selection in the dropdown.  This example shows binding the text in the textblock after choosing a value from the dropdown in the edit template.

XAML:

```
<Grid DataContext="{x:Static local:dc.Instance}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DisplayTemplate" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransactionType.Description}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditTemplate">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:dc.TransactionTypes}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                SelectedItem="{Binding TransactionType}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DGItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Transaction Type" 
                                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource DisplayTemplate}" 
                                    CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Data context class:

```
public class dc
{
    private static readonly dc _dc = new dc();
    public static dc Instance { get { return _dc;  } }


    public class TransactionTypeItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<TransactionTypeItem> TransactionTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<TransactionTypeItem>() { new TransactionTypeItem() { ID = 0, Description = "Zero" },
                                                    new TransactionTypeItem() { ID = 1, Description = "One" },
                                                    new TransactionTypeItem() { ID = 2, Description = "Two" } };
        }
    }

    public class DataItem
    {
        public TransactionTypeItem TransactionType { get; set; }
        public string OtherData { get; set; }
    }


    private List<DataItem> _items;

    public List<DataItem> DGItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
    }




    private dc()
    {
        _items = new List<DataItem>()
        {
            new DataItem() { OtherData = "Test0", TransactionType = TransactionTypes[0] },
            new DataItem() { OtherData = "Test1", TransactionType = TransactionTypes[1] },
            new DataItem() { OtherData = "Test2", TransactionType = TransactionTypes[2] },
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Only problem here is that I'd like to use a DataView as my DataGrid's ItemsSource.

Comment: That should be easy enough, change the ItemSource Path to point to your real DataView.